# Is there a publish add-on to translate google slides?

Tags: translate, add-on, google-workspace, google-slides

I am a history teacher and have been working to assist students learning English with class materials and work along with many of my co-workers.  Although it has its issues, google translate is incredibly helpful.  I had been looking for ways to translate slides efficiently when I found the "Quickstart: Translate add-on for Google Slides" page of G Suite Developers. [Link Below](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/slides/quickstart/translate).
I know a bit about code and was able to quickly follow the instructions (which were excellent) to set up the add on, but many of my co-workers may struggle with adding it to their slides.

Long story short here is the question:
I am wondering if there is an already published version of the page/Quickstart Translate add-on which people can use instead of setting up the add on manually?  I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem and have found the same document as you. Have you thought about publishing the add-on to your domain only. You can do that and the link you have links to the documentation on how to do so. You may need to work with the Google Admin in your district to make it happen though. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  I actually did go the route of publishing the add-on for our domain.  I ended up presenting the add-on to our faculty and now I am trying to add additional languages to meet the needs of our students.

Comment: Great! I ended up writing my own as well. It's simple but works wonderfully. (I have 11 languages set up for our users.)